# SSRS 2016, query for a single day

Tags: reporting-services

NEWBIE ALERT!
I'm trying to create a query to find objects for a specific day. For example I want to see records printed for 1/20/17 and only this day. I can do this for a range no problem but I'm struggling to figure out how to do it for a day. 
Any insight is appreciated!
Thanks!

ssrs report results

[image]

sql studio results

[image]

Comment: If you need only one day of data, you have to set the end date of the range to the same as the start date.

Comment: Why even set a range. Just have `i.print_date = @sdate`

Comment: I know what you're saying, I tried doing this but it returns nothing.  I added the parameter to the report so I could see how it was being populated and it showed "1/20/17 12:00:00 AM" as a value.  I can do this in type of thing in sql studio and it works "order_date  BETWEEN '09/30/16 00:00:00:000' AND '09/30/16 23:59:59:999'" but not sure how to translate this into SSRS

Comment: Then `i.print_date` must be a datetime datatype. Therefore, you could use  `Convert(varchar(8), i.print_date,112) = Convert(varchar(8), @sdate,112)` this will convert both dates to `YYYYMMDD` for equal comparison.

Comment: @WEI_DBA  That is a poorly scaling solution as you remove the sargability of the `print_date` column.

Comment: @iamdave. Thank you! I appreciate your honesty. If time were important here, OP would have specified the variables as datetime datatypes.

Comment: @cspell  The solution to this is very simple, you just need to use a `greater than or equal to` and a `less than` instead of `between`, per my answer below.

Comment: @iamdave, I appreciate your help. I simplified the query for focus.  You'll notice the table changed names, i was using a fictitious name in my example.  This is in SSRS and gives me one row only? If I query in sql studio it returns 596 rows.   "@" removed..                                                                                                                                                                                                                         SELECT i.print_date
FROM dbo.p21_view_invoice_hdr AS i
WHERE
i.print_date >= sdate 
and i.print_date < edate

Comment: @cspell  Please add some screenshots of your query within your SSRS design as well as the parameters in your SSRS report.  Without those we can't help.

Answer (score 1):

If your `print_date` is a `datetime` field rather than just a `date` you will need to take into account for the `time` element.  By this I mean `2017-01-20 13:48:00` does not actually equal `2017-01-20` because SQL Server sneakily adds on a time of `00:00:00` and the two no longer match.

To combat this, you can either convert your `datetime` values to a `date` or all to the same time, but this reduces the ability of the query optimiser to make your query more efficient, as every value needs to be read and converted *and then* compared.

Instead, to not slow down your optimiser you need to retain what is known as [SARGability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) and simply do a comparison of `datetime` values to other `datetime` values:

```
declare @sdate date    -- Remember that date types add 00:00:00 when compared to datetime.
set @sdate ='20172001' -- Make this the date you want values for.

declare @edate date
set @edate ='20172002' -- Make this the day *after* the date you want values for.
                       -- To save changing two values, you could just calculate
                       -- this value using dateadd(d,1,@sdate).

select i.print_date
from dbo.WC_view_bill_hdr as i
    join dbo.WC_view_customer as c
      on i.customer_id = c.customer_id
    join WC_view_bill_batch as ib
      on ib.bill_batch_uid = c.bill_batch_uid
where i.print_date >= @sdate  -- All values from the very start of this date.
  and i.print_date < @edate;  -- but that are less than the day after.
```

If you do your date comparisons in this manner, SQL Server can make the most efficient use of any indexes you have on your tables as well as add a degree of future proofing for more accurate `datetime` values:

For example, `datetime` is only accurate to 3 milliseconds, so the earliest value before hitting tomorrow (`2017-01-21`) would be `2017-01-20 23:59:59:997`.  If you set your query to a `between '2017-01-20 00:00:00.000' and '2017-01-20 23:59:59:997'` there is that 3 millisecond gap that *isn't yet* an issue.

If however, you moved to `datetime2` which *can* represent values greater than 997 milliseconds, you are now explicitly and erroneously excluding values you shouldn't be.

**This is an infinite problem, because there is no value for the 'end of today' before the 'start of tomorrow' that can't be further divided to infinity.**

But simply by specifying `Greater than or equal to the start of today` and `less than the start of tomorrow` you are guaranteed to get everything.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense and I am now getting results but I'm only gettting one row?

Comment: @cspell  Without being able to see your data there is not much we can do to help with that.  Are you able to add the relevant data and the expected output to your question?

Comment: I added two screenshots above. It won't let me add anymore sadly and I can't seem to add any to the comments, sigh. It shows the output from both places. The parameters are set as DateTime, Thanks

Comment: @cspell  Add images using the formatting I have edited into your question.  If you can't add another, can you please edit your report pic to be design view rather than the rendered report?  It looks like you have not built your tablix correctly.

Comment: thanks for the tip, we were able to get the results using the dd function, not sure if this is specific to our database but it works "i.print_date >= $sdate AND (i.print_date <  DATEADD(dd, 1, $edate))"

Comment: @cspell  I am not entirely sure how that is working for you as you should be adding that one day (`dd` just means `days`) to `$sdate` and not `$edate`

Comment: when we pick the date range, $sdate and $edate are the same date because we only want one day so I guess by adding a day to $edate and then using less than, it makes it return the right results. We got another approach which I didn't try yet but seems plausible,  DECLARE $edate datetime SET $edate = $edate + ' 23:59:59' SET $edate = '01-20-17' , by the way, i'm using $ in place of the "symbol it won't let me use more than once"

Comment: @cspell  Ah that makes sense.  In that case then yes, using `dateadd` on the one date parameter value is the best way to proceed :)  For your info, if you wrap your text in the grave accent character \`, you can type whatever you want: \`@TypingThis\` `@ResultsInThis`

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
declare @sdate date
set @sdate = DateAdd(day,-1,getdate())

declare @edate date
set @edate =getdate()

SELECT  i.print_date

FROM dbo.WC_view_bill_hdr AS i
JOIN dbo.WC_view_customer AS c ON i.customer_id = c.customer_id
JOIN WC_view_bill_batch AS ib ON ib.bill_batch_uid = c.bill_batch_uid

  WHERE
 i.print_date between @sdate and @edate
```

Comment: So you will return 2 days worth of data. Not what OP wants.

Comment: No it will return data from the moment to 24 hours earler

Comment: But the datatypes are `Date` not `Datetime`, so it will include yesterday and today. 2 days.

Comment: @WEI_DBA did u tried cause i've done it before and it works just fine

Comment: I tried using BETWEEN but if I used the same date it would return nothing. It seems I need to specify a from and to date but they can't be the same?

Comment: thats what i've wroten in my answer the from date like : set @ sdate = DateAdd(day,-1,getdate())
and today as : set @ edate =getdate()

Comment: @Anonymuslegacy yes your answer works in that it provides data for a single day, however as written it would be yesterday's data. The OP wanted, by way of example, today's data, so you need to set sdate to getdate() and edate to getdate() + 1